# Typescript, simplifying, value of first parameter controlling type of next parameter while using string constants

Tags: typescript

I have a function where the string value of the first parameter should control the type of the second parameter.

Using keyof I've gotten this far:

```
interface IA {
    name: string;
}

interface IB {
    age: number;
}

class Params {
    public static readonly a = "a";
    public static readonly b = "b";
}

interface ParamTypes {
    "a": IA, 
    "b": IB,
}

function printParam<ParamId extends keyof ParamTypes>(paramId: ParamId, paramValue: ParamTypes[ParamId]) : void {
    console.log(paramId, paramValue);
}

printParam(Params.a, { name: "test" });
printParam(Params.b, { age: 43 });
```

Is there some way to avoid having to specify the string "a" and "b" in two places?

Sort of like "reducing/merging" the class Params and interface ParamTypes into one thing?

Comment: FYI we have [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) in Typescript so you don’t need to create your own class.

Comment: @LindaPaiste
But I can't use that enum when setting up the lookup interface:

enum ParamTypeId {
    a = "a",
    b = "b"
}

interface ParamTypes {
    ParamTypeId.a: IA, 
    ParamTypeId.b: IB,
}

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just define `Params` as `keyof ParamTypes`:

```
type Param = keyof ParamTypes;

interface ParamTypes {
    "a": IA, 
    "b": IB,
}

function printParam<P extends Param>(paramId: P, paramValue: ParamTypes[P]) : void {
    console.log(paramId, paramValue);
}

printParam("a", { name: "test" });
printParam("b", { age: 43 });
```

In case you are wondering, the editor will provide code completion for the possible parameter names, and TypeScript will tell you if you pass a string not known to be a valid parameter.

You could also inline the Param type. I kept it around in case you want to do:

```
const paramName: Param = "a";
```

elsewhere in your code.

Comment: But the "magic string" still appear in two places.
I'd want to do
printParam(ParamTypes.a, { age: 43 });

Comment: Which "two places" are you talking about? I see it once in the definition of ParamTypes, and of course whenever the param value is actually passed by a caller. If you want TypeScript to check that passed values actually exist, you need both of those.

Comment: As you said, those two places.
I wondered if there could be some way that I could write like in my previous comment to skip specifying the string again.